# Concept of Bucketing in Seq2Seq model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, machine-translation, sequence-to-sequence

To handle sequences of different lengths we use bucketing and padding. In bucketing we make different bucket for some max_len and we do this to reduce the amount of padding, after making different buckets we train different model on different bucket.

This is what I found so far. But what I don't understand is that how this all different models trained and how they are used for translating a new sentence?

Answer (score 11):

Both at training and inference time, the algorithm needs to pick the network that is best suited for the current input sentence (or batch). Usually, it simply takes the minimal bucket which input size is greater or equal to the sentence length.

[image: bucketing]

For example, suppose there are just two buckets `[10, 16]` and `[20, 32]`: the first one takes any input up to length `10` (padded to exactly `10`) and outputs the translated sentence up to length `16` (padded to `16`). Likewise the second bucket handles the inputs up to length `20`. The two networks corresponding to these buckets accept non-intersecting input sets.

Then, for the sentence of length `8`, it's better to select the first bucket. Note that if this is a test sentence, the second bucket can handle it as well, but in this case its neural network had been trained on bigger sentences, from `11` to `20` words, so it's likely not to recognize this sentence well. The network that corresponds to the first bucket had been trained on inputs `1` to `10`, hence is a better choice.

You may be in trouble if the test sentence has the length `25`, longer than any available bucket. There's no universal solution here. The best course of action here is to trim the input to `20` words and try to translate anyway.